# Loading indicator for restangular resources

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I want to create a loading indicator like a little spinner simply indicating my angular app is currently loading stuff from the server

I am using restangular for my resources which returns promises for the requests.

My idea is the following: Create a service which gets passed the promises from restangular. Check if all promises are resolved and set loading to false by using `$q.all()`

Now i want to add a directive, which gets passed the loading variable and shows a spinner depending on loading = true / false

I created a plunkr to illustrate the idea: http://plnkr.co/edit/11QHDUkzredRpZu5NkBT?p=preview

I have some problems:

- How do i intercept the promises without adding the service in each directive requesting resources?
- The callback within my `addPromise` function gets called twice (which should be no problem, tough it could trigger the change event)
- The passed `loading` value does not reflect the changes within the service

Here the code from the plunkr:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['restangular']);

angular.module('myApp').factory('LoadingService', ['$q' , function ($q) {

    var promises = [];
    var loading = false;

    function addPromise(promise) {

        promises.push(promise);
        loading = true;

        var allPromises = $q.all(promises);

        allPromises.then(function() {
            promises = [];
            loading = false;
            console.log('finished loading');
        });

        console.log('loading');
    }

    return {
        addPromise : addPromise,
        isLoading : loading
    };

}]);


angular.module('myApp').directive('loadingIndicator', ['LoadingService', function(LoadingService) {

    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        scope : {},
        template : '<i ng-show="loading" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" />',
        link : function (scope) {
            scope.loading = LoadingService.isLoading;
        }
    };

}]);

angular.module('myApp').directive('someDirective', ['LoadingService', 'Restangular', function(LoadingService, Restangular) {

    function someDirectiveController ($scope, $q, Restangular) {

        var promise = Restangular.one('dummy').getList();

        LoadingService.addPromise(promise);

    }

    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        scope : {},
        template : '<div>I am a directive loading some stuff</div>',
        controller: ['$scope', '$q', 'Restangular', function($scope, $q, Restangular) {
            return someDirectiveController($scope, $q, Restangular);
        }]
    };

}]);
```

Answer (score 3):

For this I'd just use `requestInterceptor` to start loading and `responseInterceptor` and `errorInterceptor` to stop it and that's it :). With that you can get this loading behaviour :)

Comment: but doesn't this work for a single resource only? In the plunker i loaded some resources at the same time, so the indicator should only stop showing if all promises are fulfilled, i am currently loading about 10 different resources at a time. And the other thing i wonder about is where the interceptors are located, are they application wide? because i created customer restangular objects for doing pagination with laravel php framework

Comment: If you load more than one at the same time, just have a counter in requestInterceptor and decrease it on responseInterceptor and error. If counter goes to 0 on response or error, end loading.